# How to find_one in mongodb if the key is not always present?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a following mongodb:

some records looks like `{'_id': ObjectId('62790ce20375a639af1d8676'), 'visit_id': 594817704, 'transaction' : 10}`

some has only this form: `{'_id': ObjectId('62790ce20375a639af1d8679'), 'visit_id': 594817704}`

Using this code I can search for all collections that consists of transaction_id:

```py
collection.find({'transaction_id': { "$exists":True }
```

But if I would like to get a record with specific transaction_id, this code does not work (it tooks infinite time to search):

```py
collection.find({'transaction_id': 10})
```

I tried to combine both approaches, that is to firstly ask if transaction_id exists and then search for transaction_id = 10, but it did not work:

```py
collection.find({'transaction_id': { "$exists":True }, 'transaction_id': 10})
```

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: When you say that your code stops on first iteration, is any iteration executed? because you missed `:` in `for i in range(100)`

Comment: Also, you can include the `$exists` criteria for the `transaction_id` key - this will allow checking for existence of the key and then check for it. Also, you have the option of using the `collection.find` method - where the criteria can be `{ "transaction_id": { "$exists": True }, "transaction_id": { "$in": a_list } }` - where the `a_list` is a list with values 1 to 100. This allows to avoid the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer my code.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017);

#connect to the DB named testdb
mydatabase = client.testdb

#pickup collection named transactions 
collection = mydatabase.transactions

#find one by transaction_id
res = collection.find_one({transaction_id:10})

#display data
print(res)
```

To create index

```
collection.create_index("transaction_id");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.findOne({transaction_id: 10})
```

should work.

No need for `$exists` if you want a specific value.

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZOW-LASdjXI)

How big is your data set? do you have an index on `transaction_id`?

If your query is slow, consider add an hashed index on `transaction_id`.
Without the index, the DB should check all documents to see if any of them has `transaction_id: 1000`. This is `O(n)` operations where `n` is the number of your documents. The index stores this information, so it will be one check only `O(1)`.

In order to create the index use the UI or, using the shell:

```
db.getCollection(<collectionName>).createIndex( {transaction_id: "hashed" })
```

Where you replace `<collectionName>` with your collection name.

Comment: Thanks, it works when the transaction_id = 10 really exists. But what if it does not exist? If I try `collection.find_one({transaction_id: 1000})` it tooks again infinite time. I would like to simply get `None`, because  transaction_id = 1000 does not exist...

Comment: For this you need the index I suggested. No need to change the query. Without the index, the DB should check all documents to see if any of them as `transaction_id: 1000`. this is (O(n)). The index stores this information, so it will be one check only (O(1))

Comment: I updated the answer with details how to create it.

Comment: I think that you dont use proper python language. It should be `find_one` , `create_index`. Moreover, `collection.create_index({"transaction_id": "hashed" })` gives me error `TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
`

Comment: I'm using mongoDB syntax. Create the index in your mongoDB application